# Typo3 6.2.15 DateTime off by 1 hour

Tags: datetime, typo3, extbase

I have a model with a DateTime column named "fromDate":

```
/**
 * fromDate
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 */
protected $fromDate;
```

now I need this date to do some calculations, but when I try outputting it, it seems to be off exactly 1 hour.

```
echo $model->getFromDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This returns 2016-02-11 01:00:00 instead of 2016-02-11 00:00:00

I checked my server timezone, date_default_timezone_get() returns "Europe/Berlin" (which is correct). I tried to change the typo3 serverTimeZone (I tried 0 and 1, but doesn't change anything).

If I look at the database with phpmyadmin, the entry is "2016-02-11 00:00:00"

What am I missing, why is this happening? Any hints? Because I feel like I'm going insane, a huge calculation script is based on the correctness of $fromDate ... Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 exactly do you use?

Comment: what do you see if you render your DateTime with the timezone displayed (like "Y-m-d H:i:sT") ?

Comment: In install tool > All Configurations > Toggle all find `[SYS][serverTimeZone]` and set it to `1` (if it isn't) there is some feature in TYPO3 which tries to store datetime into DB always in UTC - and later _revert_ that converstion... it's some kind of wird...

Comment: I did set it to 1 - nothing changed

Comment: https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/209226/ have a nice reading :S

Comment: just FYI: I just checked my code, I'm using the hack that I showed in linked forum post in `DataMapper::mapDateTime()` method, I know that's ugly, but for me it was absolutely important that dates stored in MySQL as SQL datetime are identical as displayed on the page without any convertion (external API matters) - actually in TYPO3 there should be some setting for allowing to choose if dates should be stored as UTC or as-they-are :S

Comment: if I try it with "Y-m-d H:i:sT" the output is this: 2016-02-11 01:00:00CET

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$myDate = $model->getFromDate();
$myDate->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

or whatever time zone you use in your raw database table value, if not UTC.

In TYPO3 6.2, at least, doing a `findAll()` on your repository begins a series of calls -- to `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository->createQuery()`, and afterward to `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResult->rewind()`. `rewind()` calls `initialize()`, which calls `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper->map()`. `map()` calls `mapSingleRow()`, which then calls `thawProperties()` in the same class.

`TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper->thawProperties()` has a "switch case" code section based on each property data type. If the type is DateTime, `thawProperties()` calls `mapDateTime()` in the same class.

`mapDateTime()` assumes "native date/datetime values are stored in UTC", so it applies the 'UTC' DateTimeZone to the raw value. But then, `mapDateTime()` applies the DateTimeZone from the PHP [date_default_timezone_get()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) function, and returns the altered date and timezone property values to `thawProperties()` and eventually to your Extbase extension.

You can find details in the TYPO3 6.2 API [reference for mapDateTime()](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/62/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_generic_1_1_mapper_1_1_data_mapper.html#ac246d5b1e17eed1d068eba0564719341) and [its definition in DataMapper.php](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/62/html/_data_mapper_8php_source.html#l00261).

My answer is related to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26464946/4942215), [this TYPO3 Forum thread](https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/213770/), and [this TYPO3 Forum thread](https://forum.typo3.org/index.php?t=msg&goto=534664&).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in the DateTime handling of Extbase, which was recently fixed for TYPO3 7.6 and 8 (dates were not interpreted as UTC). We won’t backport the fix for 6.2 officially, but you can of course apply it yourself.

If you don’t want to patch the core, you can also create an extension class for the relevant part (`DataMapper`) and override the method (`mapDateTime()`).